# row justify-content-between is not working in two divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have two divs, I want one to the left and the other to the right ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GayHf.png)).
I've tried `self-align-start` and `self-align-end` in each column, but it didn't result in what I want. I also put the class `row-cols-1` (not in the screenshot).

What am I missing? Here's my code:

```css
.about-me {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.current-work {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="about" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 justify-content-between">
      <div class="about-me col-6">
        <h2> About Me </h2>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          <p>
      </div>

      <div class="current-work col-6">
        <h2> What I'm Doing </h2>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          <p>
      </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

And [here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeKsJ.png)

Comment: You want to center both divs or? Have you tried `margin: 0 auto;` ?

Comment: @DaMaGex no, I don't want to center them, I want one on the left and the other one on the right, like in the second image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `offset-3` in the second div class attribute.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9">
                <div class="item">
                    <h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat incidunt odit, amet cupiditate sint aliquid possimus ut? Aliquam, repellat sit expedita suscipit quaerat harum nesciunt molestiae iure, nobis quae earum deleniti odio provident. Soluta magni quo incidunt ducimus tempora nisi?t amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat incidunt odit, amet cupiditate sint aliquid possimus ut? Aliquam, repellat sit expedita suscipit quaerat harum nesciunt molestiae iure, nobis quae earum deleniti odio provident. Soluta magni quo incidunt ducimus tempora nisi?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9 offset-3 text-end">
                <div class="item">
                    <h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat incidunt odit, amet cupiditate sint aliquid possimus ut? Aliquam, repellat sit expedita suscipit quaerat harum nesciunt molestiae iure, nobis quae earum deleniti odio provident. Soluta magni quo incidunt ducimus tempora nisi?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.me-auto` & `.text-start` for left aligned, and use `.ms-auto` & `.text-end` for right aligned.

```css
:root {
  --heavy-red-border: 1em solid red;
}

.red-border-start {
  border-left: var(--heavy-red-border);
}

.red-border-end {
  border-right: var(--heavy-red-border);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-9 me-auto text-start red-border-start">
        <div class="item">
          <h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat incidunt odit, amet cupiditate sint aliquid possimus ut? Aliquam, repellat sit expedita suscipit quaerat harum nesciunt molestiae iure, nobis quae earum deleniti odio provident.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9 ms-auto text-end red-border-end">
        <div class="item">
          <h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat incidunt odit, amet cupiditate sint aliquid possimus ut? Aliquam, repellat sit expedita suscipit quaerat harum nesciunt molestiae iure, nobis quae earum deleniti odio provident.
            Soluta magni quo incidunt ducimus tempora nisi?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```